# Найти самого большого элемента в массиве без метода .map

Tags: javascript

При нажатии "b" выполняем функцию "f". Функция должна вывести в "out" длину самого большого вложенного массива в "a". То есть ожидаем 6. Не знаю как решить. Нужно решить задачу без всяких методов массива типа .map.
Кажется можно решить задачу с циклами и условиями if. Но не знаю как.

```
let a = [
    [],
    [1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    [1, 2]
];

function f() {
    let max = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        // Дальше не знаю что писать
    }

    document.querySelector('.out').innerHTML = max;
}

document.querySelector('.b').onclick = f;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Берём каждый элемент массива по порядку (`a[i]`)
2. Если длина массива (**[length](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)**) на текущей итерации больше, чем `max`, то заносим это значение в `max`
3. Всё

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!!!

Comment: for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i].length > max) { 
   max = a[i].length; 
  }
 }

Вот так?

Comment: @Asylbek да,...

Answer (score 0):

Сам нашел решение:

```
for (let i = 0; i < a15.length; i++) {
        let maxIndex = a15[i].length - 1; // Длина каждого элемента в массиве
        if (maxIndex > max) { // Пока длина элемента массива больше чем max
            max = maxIndex; // max присваиваем Длину элемента массива
        }
    }
```

Comment: Неверно. В одной строчке (второй) тут ошибка

Comment: Не понял в чем заключается ошибка? Подскажите.

Comment: возьмите любой одномкерный массив с несколькиими значениями. и посмотрите что выведет в коноль если считать длину массива так, как написано у вас в коде

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, не пишите чепуху. В данном случае массив многомерный - элементы массива являются массивами, поэтому у них доступно свойство length

Comment: @SanyaH вначале вникни в суть моих слов, посмотри что там написано, а потом  пиши свои **обдуманные** комментарии

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я прекрасно понял что там написано. Вопрос - зачем писать про одномерный массив, если речь идет о многомерном, у элементов которого доступно свойство length ?

Comment: @SanyaH Давай попробуем ещё раз: посмотри ооочень внимательно на код. Посмотри на конкретную строчку. Затем прочитай три комментария под кодом и сопоставь для **чего именно**  я рекомендую сделать это действие, которое **никак не является способом решения задачи**, а намёком на ошибку в коде автора

Comment: @АлексейШиманский извините, я под ошибкой воспринял возможную ошибку компиляции, а не математическую )